# Python websocket: save data to variable

Tags: python, websocket

relatively new coder here:

I have a connection with a websocket which gives me the following responses:

Response: {'event': 'ticker', 'market': 'LINK-EUR', 'bestBid': '20.486', 'bestBidSize': '463.65240991'}

Response: {'event': 'ticker', 'market': 'LINK-EUR', 'bestBid': '20.486', 'bestBidSize': '499.19116109'}
...

I am wondering what would be the best way to save (and update) specific data from this response to a variable in order to use it later.

Currently I am running this code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk1LI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in a text file and get the data back by using the json module.

Or you can store the responses in a list like this:-

```
List = []
List.append(Response)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I already tried using list but I keep getting back an empty list if I do it this way.